# How to get live data from an old machine with an HDMI-cable?

Tags: python, hdmi

I am working on an assignment at a production company. For my project I need data from a very old machine. I am not allowed to work with the computer of the machine as it is very sensitive to malfunctions. I can work with output cable like an HDMI-cable or the machine's screen.

The information I need is on the screen of the machine. I have written a Python program that takes a screenshot of a screen every 10 seconds and then reads the values in the screenshot and saves them. In the ideal world I would run this program on the computer of the machine so it can take screenshots of the machine's screen, but as said earlier that is not possible.

So I had an idea that I want to test here if it is possible. I want to kind of “tap” the computer as there goes an HDMI cable from the computer to the screen. Is it in a way possible to split the HDMI-cable, put an HDMI-cable in my laptop, display the computers screen on my laptop aswell and then read the screen with my Python code. Would this be possible? If so how can I do it?

Maybe I've come up with total nonsense. Then I'd like to hear it aswell. If you have other suggestions what I can do, please let me know.

Comment: Many external HDMI capture devices have a pass through port. HDMI goes straight through, and the video shows up as a "camera" type device over USB that you could pull video or single images from.

Comment: So you generally cannot "tap" an HDMI connection, because of the HDCP protocol. its designed to prevent video piracy by encrypting the signal all the way to the monitor. a capture device like the Mokubai suggested may help, but you would have to install additional hardware.

Comment: @FrankThomas, there are HDMI splitters that strip/ignore HDCP, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/review/R39ZITPLZGNSTC . That does not mean I condone copyright infringement -- just that the devices *do* exist. See also https://laptopreviewpro.com/best-hdmi-splitter-hdcp-bypass/

Comment: Interesting. yes one of those non-compliant devices that should not exist might just do the trick. and we're just talking tech, I'm sure no one thinks you condone or condemn any particular activity.

Comment: Also, even with HDCP being a thing, it's not like HDMI cannot work without it. DRM'd video players might refuse to work if the HDMI connection is not HDCP-enabled, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible this way, since the screenshot, in spite of its
name, is not taken from the screen. The data is actually coming
from the display-adapter of the old machine, which you're not
allowed to touch.

As remarked by user gronostaj in the comments, HDMI capture devices
do exist. Some are small USB devices that emulate a webcam,
and which are pretty cheap.

If the old computer's screen is connected by an HDMI cable,
it should be possible to add an HDMI splitter that will connect
to the monitor and to your HDMI capture device.
I have no experience with such devices and can't recommend any.

You should also ensure that you have enough disk space for the images.
The size of an image will depend on the resolution at which you set
the webcam capture software.